# Django custom field: when, exactly, do I have to write a deconstructor?

Tags: python, django

Reading from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/) for custom fields (under "Field deconstruction"):

> If you haven’t added any extra options on top of the field you
>   inherited from, then there’s no need to write a new deconstruct()
>   method. If, however, you’re changing the arguments passed in
>   __init __() (like we are in HandField), you’ll need to supplement the values being passed.

The example provided (excluding the deconstructor code), `HandField`, is:

```
from django.db import models

class HandField(models.Field):

    description = "A hand of cards (bridge style)"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 104
        super(HandField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My question is: What exactly are this "extra options" the documentation is talking about? What exactly makes the creation of a deconstructor compulsive in the above example? Isn't calling `super(HandField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`exactly like calling the field from which we inherited from? Or is `kwargs['max_length'] = 104` the point in which we're adding an extra argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better example of adding an extra option is `CommaSepField` in the documentation. It adds a `separator` argument, so `deconstruct` method has to be overridden to add it to the kwargs.

In the case of `HandField`, the `max_length` is **always** 104. Therefore there's no point in the `deconstruct` method including `max_length` in kwargs, since it's hardcoded. Overriding the `deconstruct` method and removing `max_length` makes it tidier.

As I understand it, the documentation says that overriding `deconstruct` for the `HandField` is optional. It is possible to do `HandField(max_length=104)`, but it's unnecessary, since the value will be overridden in `__init__`. However, it is necessary to add `separator` to the kwargs in `CommaSepField`, otherwise it won't be possible to reconstruct the field.